# How can I optimize an animated PNG (APNG)?

Tags: compression, png, web-development

I have an animated PNG that is about 150KB. It’s 24 frames. If I run it through a typical PNG optimizer like ImageOptim or Squash, it turns into a non-animated PNG of 3KB and one frame.

I am dead sure that the animated PNG can/should be much smaller than 150KB, but I do not know of any tool that can optimize an animated PNG. Do you?

The tool should work on a Mac or online, for my purposes.

Comment: Wikipedia site of APNG contains a list of software that supports this format, I would start testing the editors of this list.

Comment: 150kb really doesn't sound like much for an animated png since this format doesn't use compression. You could use something else like webp or a mp4 that loops....

Comment: @RicardoBohner APNG does use lossless compression

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks for the clarification'll do a search to find out what that really means....

Comment: @RicardoBohner Imagine you have a 9x9 mural made out of tiles. But it is entirely blue. I could tell you 'use a blue tile for every square' and this is lossless compression; it is entirely accurate while being more efficient than me telling you that tile 1 is blue, tile 2 is blue, ..., tile 81 is blue. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I recommend [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/), I'm satisfied with the results and they recently added support for aPNGs.

Comment: That worked brilliantly! 146KB down to 32KB, while retaining the animation! Thanks a lot!!